# Get comma separated column headers of all columns where value > 0 from a row

Tags: excel

I want to get all column headers names where they are greater than zero for a row.

So far I have tried this `=IF(COUNTA($A2:$E2)=0,"",INDEX($A$1:$E$1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($A2:$E2>0,0),0))`

It gives me the name of the first column which is greater than zero.

```
a   b   c   d   e   
0   1   0   1   1   b
1   0   0   1   0   a
```

Whereas I need something like this

```
a   b   c   d   e   
0   1   0   1   1   b,d,e
1   0   0   1   0   a,d
```

I have never worked with excel before. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Your column number is dynamic or fixes? Like column may be 5, 6, 7 or you want it for only 5 columns what you shared in your question?

Comment: @harun24hr It is not dynamic. It will be fixed like in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula in `F2` cell and fill down.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(CONCATENATE(IF(A2>0,$A$1 & " ",""),IF(B2>0,$B$1& " ",""),IF(C2>0,$C$1& " ",""),IF(D2>0,$D$1& " ",""),IF(E2>0,$E$1,"")))," ",",")
```

[image]

Comment: Could you also give a dynamic solution for this if possible. i.e. for more columns

Comment: I will try to do it for dynamic columns and will know by comment.

Comment: It would be great if you could help. You could update the answer then.

Answer (score 2):

I realise the answer above does the job and mine is probably a bit complicated if you do no need anything more dynamic.

However, if you do need a more dynamic solution, you can do this:
Assuming your header is in cells A1:E1 and your data underneath, the first step is to get a function return the values that match your criteria:
=IF(A2:E2>0,A$1:E$1,"")
You need to enter this as an array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter)

This returns an array which returns loads of blanks, so there are two more things we need to take care of:
1. Remove blanks from that array
2. Concatenate the array so that it returns a comma separated string

Unfortunately Excel does not have any of these functions (which is a shame really), so you need some VBA magic:

```
Public Function joinArray(arr As Variant)
   arr = arr
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim s As String: s = ""
   For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
      s = s & arr(i) & ","
   Next i
   joinArray = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
End Function

Public Function Strip(arr As Variant)
   arr = arr
   Dim v() As Variant
   Dim k As Integer, i As Integer
   For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
      If arr(i) <> "" Then
         ReDim Preserve v(0 To k)
         v(k) = arr(i)
         k = k + 1
      End If
   Next i
   Strip = v
End Function
```

You can now call =joinarray(strip(IF(A2:E2>0,A$1:E$1,""))) as an array formula (Ctrl + Shift + Enter)

Comment: Will try it in VBA in some time. This would also help.